# Как начать работать с Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, telegram, бот, vps

Написал телеграмм бота и хочу поставить на него базу данных **postgresql**, не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать как настроить. На данном этапе нахожусь на покупке **VPS**. Что с ним дальше делать не знаю.. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Брать любой учебник про sql/postgresql и читать, например?

Comment: Не рановато VPS покупать?